# How to set minecraft camera projection to ortographic?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

It would be really handy for building, like for viewing it from the top, etc.
Ive seems many images on the internet, but I dont know if theres a command or mod for that.

Comment: most of them are meshed worlds that are rendered in 3d software like blender or 3dsmax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Vanilla. The closest you can get is setting your FOV very narrow and flying far away.

There are programs that generate big overviews of entire Minecraft worlds, but I think those aren't usually Minecraft mods, but completely separate. [Here](http://overviewer.org/) is one of them (from a [comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354867/how-to-set-minecraft-camera-projection-to-ortographic/354886?noredirect=1#comment499768_354886)).

Comment: Take a look [here](http://overviewer.org/).

Comment: it's not vanilla though

Comment: It's not even Minecraft. My answer already says that it's not possible in Vanilla.